# Tap on Invisible element iOS Appium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-ios

I need to tap on the button **"Choose"** which is invisible while inspecting using Appium inspector.While running the script the "choose" button is not detected , Is there any alternate way to tap on the button.

[image]

Comment: It should detect , Can you post inspect element part of that button? I mean android properties of that button.

Comment: "//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[2]/UIAButton[3]" <- following is the xpath for the button , only when the "show invisible" is selected in the Appium inspector.

Comment: is it your app. button or default device button?

Comment: default device button. Both the "Cancel" and "Choose" button are not tappable even if I inspect and provide the ID.

Comment: Is this gallery view?

Comment: yes it is gallery view.

Comment: this might help - you should set attribute - visible to true https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1615141-isaccessibilityelement

Answer (score 0):

I created this method in ruby to access elements that are not displayed on screen, it works also to scroll to an element that is not visible yet, it should work to click on invisible elements too

```
def btn_name(value)
  #find a button by its name, visible or not
  ele_by_json(typeArray: ['UIAButton'], onlyVisible: false, name: {target: value, substring: false, insensitive: false})
end
```

and then I call it this way

```
btn_name('Choose').click
```

Other way to be sure if appium really cant find your button, or even to know what is appium finding on screen is using the command bellow, it will print each visible button name:

```
buttons.each {|b| puts b.name}
```

This looks like an ios button, not an app button, maybe thats why it is not finding it, if so, just replace the classType

```
eles_by_json(typeArray: ['CLASSTYPEOFTHATBUTTON'], onlyVisible: false)
```